# Remember-me in Spring Security doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, filter, spring-security

Faced the following problem: when you try to delete the JSESSIONID or restart the browser, the next request to the server resets the remember-me Cookie and does not confirm the session.

```
http
            .authenticationManager(authManager(http))
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/auth/sendCode", "/login").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/api/*").hasAuthority("USER")
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
            .and()
            .formLogin().passwordParameter("code").usernameParameter("email")
            .successHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            }).failureHandler((request, response, exception) -> response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED))
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .and()
            .rememberMe()        .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())
.userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
            .alwaysRemember(true)
            .tokenValiditySeconds(24*60*60*14)
            .key("Mykey");
    return http.build();

    @Bean
public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository(){
    JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl tokenRepository = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
    tokenRepository.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return tokenRepository;
}
```

When requested from any of the authorized user paths, a 401 is returned from exceptionHandling(). There are two Set-Cookies in a row in the response headers:

```
Set-Cookie: remember-me=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/

Set-Cookie: remember-me=aFRLMWhLYkhmNzVLMWh6M2I0b2ZYQSUzRCUzRDo2Snd1ZWFkcTFZRGlzZXp4RjAwRHlBJTNEJTNE; Max-Age=1209600; Expires=Thu, 29-Jun-2023 23:40:17 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly
```

There is a table in the database and every time a new remember-me token is created:
[persistent table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8TO2.png)

It is necessary that the cookie is not reset and works all the time tokenValiditySeconds. Please, tell me what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved like this: UserDetailsService uses a request to the repository, looking for a user by email. Spring was passing the decrypted email correctly, but adding a line break.

So far I've replaced this:

```
repo.findByEmail(email.replaceAll("\n","")
```

After that, the user became located, the session was confirmed. I'll see where the line wrapping came from and, if anything, I'll supplement the answer.